# jQuery Autocomplete. On select, alert a value of which is in the suggestion's 

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I jQuery autocomplete plugin for a movie search. Each movie gets an id of which is from IMDb's ID. Now the way I parse that ID is from PHP and is enclosed inside a span with class="imdbID". So it looks something likes this:

```
<li>Movie title 1<span class="imdbID">tt345813</span></li>
<li>Movie title 1<span class="imdbID">tt346413</span></li>
<li>Movie title 1<span class="imdbID">tt789675</span></li>
<li>Movie title 1<span class="imdbID">tt185858</span></li>
```

and goes on. Here's how it looks with a real example: http://www.screenr.com/aH0s

Now, I want to select a movie and alert that imdbID value.

If I use this method:

```
select:function(a,b){
        var bbbb = $(".imdbID").text();
        alert(bbbb);
}
```

I get all the span's value like this:

[image]

So my question is, how can I get only the .imdbID of the selected autocomplete value?

Thank you

Comment: Has the value actually been selected yet? Your example looks like you're in the process of selecting, but only the first one is highlighted so far.

Comment: It looks like you're displaying the `imdbId` in the list of results. What does your JSON look like? If you can make it a property in the array of objects that autocomplete is fueled by, you'll be able to pull it out later...

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker This is where I asked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735795/jquery-autocomplete-on-event-select-submit-php-value-of-which-is-parsed-from-an and because I had no answer I thought of doing it this way and set the visibility of the imdbID to hidden and still submit it.

Comment: @kinakuta It's because the value's are parsed from PHP and I set the value to be displayed just the name but the results display the year and the ID. This is how I parse them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735795/jquery-autocomplete-on-event-select-submit-php-value-of-which-is-parsed-from-an

Comment: @jQuerybeast: It may help to post your HTML and JavaScript somewhere like http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: It's because most of it is PHP. There is nothing more than the above JS. As for the HTML is just an input. I can paste you the PHP if you can spare some time and help me? I really want this! I've been fighting for it now lol

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker http://jsfiddle.net/eqh2Z/ Note that it won't work because it needs an TMDb API key but thats the entire code. Thanks

Comment: @jQuerybeast: If you return the `imdbid` in the array of objects that is used as the `source` to your autocomplete, it will make your life much easier: `[{ id: 'id', value: 'value', imdbid: 'xxxxyyy' }, ... ]`

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker Do you mean that after I select the movie to parse the ID aswell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referencing your other question for the PHP code, I would do something like this (*please take with a grain of salt, I do not know PHP*):

```
$tmdb = new TMDb($api_key);
$json = json_decode($tmdb->searchMovie($_GET['term']));
$response = array();
$i=0;
foreach($json as $movie){
    if(!$movie->imdb_id || $movie->adult) continue;
    if($i >= 6) break;
    $response[$i]['value'] = $movie->name;
    $response[$i]['label'] = $movie->name . ' <small>(' . date('Y',strtotime($movie->released)).')</small><span><span> (' . $movie->imdb_id . ')';
    $response[$i]['imdbid'] = $movie->imdb_id;
    $i++;
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

The idea being that you add `imdbid` as a property of the JSON payload you're sending to the client.

Then on the select event:

```
$("input").autocomplete({
    /* snip */
    select: function (event, ui) {
        alert(ui.item.imdbid); // <-- alert the imdbid property
    }
});
```

Comment: What you are trying to do is what my first question was. It's the idea what I want to achieve but I couldn't think of how to do it. Thanks alot sir!!

Comment: I ended up asking two question to get this answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The callback receives two arguments `function(event, ui)`.  e.originalEvent should give you the click event that triggered the select event, along with its target `ul`.

```
$(e.originalEvent.target).find(".imdbID").text(); //Gets you the IMDB key
```

Comment: `ui.item` is not a DOM element.

Comment: Updated the answer to something that should work, but Andrew's way is probably better.