# Retrieving data with PHP and Json into an autocomplete. Problems with jQuery UI 1.8.2+

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I made a movie autocomplete of which you type a letter and it gives you a suggest list of movies. Next to each movie I also added the date the movie was released.

This is how I parse it in PHP:

```
$tmdb = new TMDb($api_key);
$json = json_decode($tmdb->searchMovie($_GET['term']));
$response = array();
$i=0;
foreach($json as $movie){
    if($i >= 6) break;
    $response[$i]['value'] = $movie->name;
    $response[$i]['label'] = $movie->name . ' <span class="m_rel">(' . date('Y',strtotime($movie->released)).')</span>';

    $i++;
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

Now, if I use jQuery 1.8.2 everything works perfectly.

I get this result:

[image]

Where if I use a later version of the jQuery UI I get this:

[image]

The html is simple, its just a form and the autocomplete its the one from the jQuery so nothing fancy. Once I change the version of the UI, the problem happens.

Could someone please help me on how can I solve this issue? I can't use jQuery 1.8.2 because I'm getting other problems with draggable and IE (all versions) which cant be solved since its a known bug.

My JS after Andrew's Whitaker answer:

```
var movieName = $('#movieName');
movieName.autocomplete({
    source: 'movieInfo.php',
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).val(ui.item.imdbid);
        $(".re5").submit()
    }
})._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    return $("<li></li>")
        .data("item.autocomplete", item)
        .append("<a>" + item.label + "<span class='m_rel'>" + item.releasedate + "</span></a>")
        .appendTo(ul);
};
```

're5' is the class of the form.

Thanks alot

Comment: The issue should be in your js html code not add that code too,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preferred way to override the way that menu items look with autocomplete is to replace the default `_renderItem` method, as shown in this [example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#custom-data).

So I would do two things:

1. Modify your PHP not to return markup in the results:

   ```
   $tmdb = new TMDb($api_key);
   $json = json_decode($tmdb->searchMovie($_GET['term']));
   $response = array();
   $i=0;
   foreach($json as $movie){
       if($i >= 6) break;
       $response[$i]['value'] = $movie->name;
       $response[$i]['label'] = $movie->name;
       $response[$i]['releasedate'] = $movie->released;

       $i++;
   }
   echo json_encode($response);
   ```
2. Override the `_renderItem` method to display the release date in a `span`:

   ```
   $("#selector").autocomplete({ /* options */ })
       .data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
           return $("<li></li>")
               .data("item.autocomplete", item)
               .append("<a>" + item.label + " <span class='m_rel'>(" + item.releasedate + ")</span></a>")
               .appendTo(ul);
       };
   ```

*Sorry if the PHP is a little off; I'm not an expert there.*

Comment: Hi there Andrew! I was hoping I was getting an answer from you. Can you please note that this is what I use in terms of my javascript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745577/jquery-autocomplete-on-select-alert-a-value-of-which-is-in-the-suggestions. An answer I was given for you. I still use that IMDbID. So my current javascript is (check my edit above), which doesn't show the date. Thanks alot

Comment: @jQuerybeast: Hmm, you should be able to combine the PHP above with the PHP from the previous answer... What problem are you having specifically?

Comment: nah the php is still the same. Except that extra one line of $response[$i]['imdbid'] = $movie->imdb_id; at the end which the IMDb ID to submit the form. I don't get any errors, is just the date is not shown.

Comment: Can you add the following to your `select` handler and see if it alerts correctly? `alert(ui.item.releasedate);`

Comment: It does alert the entire date. For example 1999-07-01

Comment: Okay, so that's half the battle. That means the date *is* being sent down (albeit in the incorrect format). So it's something wrong with the `_renderItem` function...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4397/discussion-between-andrew-whitaker-and-jquerybeast)

Comment: How can I thank you. It's an entire web app and only that bug was missing! Are you really 23 years old by the way?